# iOS 6 - Responding to Keyboard Done Button State

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In the iOS Apprentice Series eBooks, you are supposed to build a Checklist app. The tutorials have you go through and make a Done button on a button bar that is disabled and enabled based on the text inside of a UITextField object.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *newText = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

self.doneBarButton.enabled = ([newText length] > 0);

return YES;
}
```

Now, the keyboard is set to disable the Done button (on the keyboard) if the text field is empty. Is there a way to observe the state of the keyboard done button and have the done button bar button reflect it accordingly?

IE, when the keyboard done button is enabled, the button bar done button is enabled.

Comment: That is what the above code which you posted does. What is the issue with above code?

Comment: I'll try to clarify: How does the keyboard know that text has been entered into the field? It seems wasteful to respond to every change in the textfield.

Comment: In that case it will didEndEditing delegate method. You can add the above line that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextField` supports what you want through the `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically` property. This property is from the `UITextInputTraits` protocol.

When you create your `UITextField`, set this property.

```
self.textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
```

This means the Return key (whatever it is labeled) will automatically becomes disabled if the text field is empty. And it automatically becomes enabled when text is entered.

There is no way to observe the state of this so you must implement the code you already have for `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to update your other Done button.

Comment: It seems wasteful to me to check every change that is made to the textfield for the sole purpose of enabling or disabling a button. How does the keyboard know the state of the textfield?

Comment: The same way. Don't worry about it being "wasteful". If, later on, you discover your app is too slow because of this check, deal with it then. Don't optimize until you know something needs to be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a target on your text field with the following events.

```
UIControlEventEditingDidBegin    
UIControlEventEditingChanged     
UIControlEventEditingDidEnd      
UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit
UIControlEventAllEditingEvents
```

Example:
In `viewDidLoad`

```
[_textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEditingEvents];
```

Action Method:

```
- (void)textFieldEditing:(id)sender
{
    _doneButton.enable = ([[sender text] length]>0);
}
```

Comment: None of this does what is being asked in the question. There are `UITextFieldDelegate` methods that you can implement for each of those events. No need to add a target/action for each. That is only needed if you need some other class to observe the events besides the test field's delegate.